# Downloading Large Google Drive files with WebClient in C#

Tags: c#, cookies, google-drive-api, webclient

I know there are tones of questions on this subject already. After reading all the threads, I decided to get a redirected URL in a confirmation HTML page and then use it as a direct link to download.

As you know, the original URL format of the direct download link is like this.

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=XXXXX..

But if the size of the target file is big, then it is like this.

https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=RRRR&id=XXXXX..

I can get RRRR from the first downloaded data, so I need to try twice in order to download the real file. The concept is very simple enough but I can't get this to work.

```
class Test
{
    class MyWebClient: WebClient
    {
        CookieContainer c = new CookieContainer();

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri u)
        {
            var r = (HttpWebRequest) base.GetWebRequest(u);
            r.CookieContainer = c;
            return r;
        }
    }

    static string GetRealURL(string filename)
    {
        // Some Jobs to Parse....
        return directLink;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        MyWebClient wc = new MyWebClient();

        string targetLink = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=XXXXXXX";
        wc.DownloadFile(targetLink, "tempFile.tmp");

        targetLink = GetRealURL("tempFile.tmp");
        wc.DownloadFile(targetLink, "realFile.dat");
    }
}
```

What did I wrong?
I can get the right download link from the first file, but I get another confirmation page file with another confirm code on the second try. I thought this was because of cookies, so I created my own `WebClient` class as you can see above.

Also I originally used `DownloadFileAsync()`, and changed it to `DownloadFile()` just in case, but the same result..
I'm still thinking it has something to do with cookie things.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try using [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to watch the traffic that HTTP requests that successfully download the file vs. the one's your code produces.  It should help you identify what is causing the problem.

Comment: @erdomke Thanks for the info :) I'll try what you said. BTW is fiddler better than wireshark? I've never used them both.

Comment: wireshark is designed to trace all network traffic and operates at a lower level which makes it more powerful, but harder to discern the http traffic. It is also cross platform. Fiddler is Windows only, but as purely an http proxy, I find it easier to discern the http traffic.

Comment: @erdomke I'm looking into Fiddler now and really appreciate your advice, regardless of whether it would solve my problem or not. I'd heard of Fiddler and Wireshark before, but never even thought about using them because I'm not a network guy. But thanks to you, I just got into one of them and found it very useful!! Just one more question though. As you can see, I'm using only `DownloadFile()` method of `WebClient` class for now, then don't I need Wireshark in this case at all? I checked the traffic with Fiddler, and just got a few sessions

Comment: Yes, any method you call on the `WebClient` class will be handled via HTTP and will be captured by Fiddler.  Therefore, Fiddler should be sufficient for debugging what is going on.  Basically, your goal is to use Fiddler capture the HTTP calls for a situation that works (e.g. by downloading the file in the browser) and compare those to what you capture when running your code.  There is likely an authentication header or cookie that the browser is sending which your code is not.

Comment: @erdomke Oh, I see. It helped a lot, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this same problem but had solved it in an HttpClient. I tried via your approach with WebClient and was able to get it to work. You don't show your `GetRealUrl()` source, but i'm willing to bet in there lies the issue. Here's how I did it:

- You need to parse the html response to get the url in the href attribute of the "download anyway" button. It will only have the relative url, (the `/uc?export=download...` part)
- You need to replace the xml escape character `&amp;` with `&`
- Then you can build the url using thte domain `https://drive.google.com`

At which point you can download the file. Here's the source (used in a test WPF application):

```
class MyWebClient : WebClient
{
    CookieContainer c = new CookieContainer();

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri u)
    {
        var r = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(u);
        r.CookieContainer = c;
        return r;
    }
}

private async void WebClientTestButtonGdrive_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (MyWebClient client = new MyWebClient())
    {
        //get the warning page
        string htmlPage = await client.DownloadStringTaskAsync("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=XXXXXXX&export=download");

        //use HtmlAgilityPack to get the url with the confirm parameter in the url
        HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
        document.LoadHtml(htmlPage);
        HtmlNode node = document.DocumentNode;
        HtmlNode urlNode = node.SelectSingleNode(@"//a[contains(@href, 'XXXXXXX') and contains(@id, 'uc-download-link')]//@href");
        string downloadUrl = urlNode.Attributes["href"].Value;
        downloadUrl = downloadUrl.Replace("&amp;", "&");
        downloadUrl = "https://drive.google.com" + downloadUrl;

        //download the file
        if (File.Exists("FileToDownload.zip"))
            File.Delete("FileToDownload.zip");
        await client.DownloadFileTaskAsync(downloadUrl, "FileToDownload.zip");
    }
}
```

Comment: It was more than five years ago and I don't remember how I  implemented the `GetRealURL()` method.
I think I already checked the URL returned by it at that time, but I also think I might have made some stupid mistake there as you said.
I soon gave up on it because the Google Drive quota wasn't enough for the project.
But it's great to know the `CookieContainer` hack works with Google Drive, even in 2022!
Thanks!